# Dangerous MySQL functions

Tags: security, sql-injection

It is well-known that the SQL function `SLEEP()` can be used to attack web applications, e.g. as described [here](https://blog.pythian.com/mysql-injection-sleep/). The sleep function [cannot be disabled](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-sleep-and-benchmark-functions-in-MySQL) since it is compiled into the MySQL code and does not require any special privilege.

My question is: does MySQL include any functions *except* `SLEEP()` which have all of the following properties?

1. The function is not commonly required by web applications. Say, 95% of CRUD apps don't need to use the function.
2. The function is not provided by an external plugin, but is included in the core MySQL codebase.
3. The function does not require any special privileges to be executed.
4. The function provides *some* non-zero benefit to attackers in a SQL injection.

My motivation for the question: I am interested in techniques to prevent SQL injections by limiting MySQL functionality. I am curious if `SLEEP()`-injections are the only candidate for this technique or if there are other attacks that could be prevented.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking in a bad way. Those security limits can get back to bite you.

The right solution is to sanitize user input etc. to prevent injection to happen.

SQL Injection isn't an error on the database side instead it is on the application side.

If you try to protect only db somebody will attack the app server and once there he can do full dump.

Comment: Validation is the first line of defense, certainly, but if I know my application won't use `SLEEP` what harm is there in disabling the functionality? That way life is a bit harder for the attacker in the event I made a mistake in my validation, right?

Comment: `DROP TABLE very_import_data;` will have much worse effect on your application than `SLEEP()`. And you certainly can't or shouldn't disable DDL. So why are you worried about SLEEP or other functions?

Comment: I am not eligible to decide since I don't know the full code of MySQL but most of non-enduser's functions are used in the system. So disabling them may have unexpected results.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Realy `DROP` would require DROP PRIVILEGES which aplication user mostly don't have. Biger fun is something like `UPDATE 'ORDERS' SET id=0 WHERE id IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: `DELETE FROM orders;` can be equally devastating, true.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Would that require any privileges? I'm interested in `SLEEP` because it only requires base privileges. Also, if an application has many SQL queries in its code, one could imagine a system where each query is annotated with allowed functionality (outside of some base functionality like INSERT / SELECT), so instead of granting privileges across the board one could limit privileges per-query